# Change value of array without overwriting the old array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here i am trying to rotate the array to 90deg clockwise,
I assigned the value of 'mat' to 'new array'(line:9).
When i am trying to overwrite the value of 'new array' (line:13) the value of the 'mat' array is also getting overwritten resulting changing of the actual value and giving error on the result , suggest me some edits to stop overwriting of the 'mat' array

```
class maxpop {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rotation();
}
static void Rotation(){
    int[][] mat = {{0,0,0},{1,1,1},{2,2,2}};
    int[][] newarray = new int[mat.length][mat.length];
    int p;
    newarray=mat;
    for (int i = 0; i < newarray.length; i++) {
        p=mat.length-1;
        for (int j = 0; j <newarray.length; j++,p--) {
            newarray[i][j] = newarray[p][i];
        }
        
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < newarray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newarray.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(newarray[i][j]);
        }
        //p--;
        System.out.println();
    }}}
```

Comment: Right. .. when you do `newarray=mat` then both "newarray" and "mat" both point to the same array. Changes in one will be seen in the other.  Get rid of that line, then change `newarray[i][j] = newarray[p][i];` to `newarray[i][j] = mat[p][i];` and see how that changes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are doing newarray=mat both array is pointing the same object , change in one will alter the other
to stop overwriting the mat array and to rotate 90deg

```
class maxpop {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rotation();
}
static void Rotation(){
    int[][] mat = {{0,0,0},{1,1,1},{2,2,2}};
    int[][] newarray = new int[mat.length][mat.length];
    int p;
    int k=0;
 while (k<no of times you want to rotate) {
    for (int i = 0; i < newarray.length; i++) {
        p =mat.length-1;
        for (int j = 0; j <newarray.length; j++,p--) {
            newarray[i][j] = mat[p][i];
            System.out.print(newarray[i][j]);
        } 
        System.out.println();   
    }
   int[][] newarrray_2=new int[newarray.length] 
   [newarray.length];/*everytime the loop runs it will create 
    newobject with 0 
    values, if you don't create a new array each time 
    newarry,newarray_2 
    will 
   point the same object,and newarray will not get initialised to 
   0 later*/
   mat=newarray;//mat will get overwrite 
   newarray=newarrray_2;/*a new 0 value will be initialised to 
    new array*/
   k++;
}
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
int[][] mat = {{0,0,0},{1,1,1},{2,2,2}};   // (A)
int[][] newarray = new int[mat.length][mat.length];   // (B)
int p;
newarray=mat;
```

The line `newarray=mat;` assigns a reference to the old array to the `newarray` variable.  The fresh array you created and assigned to `newarray` in (B) will no longer be accessible. Both `mat` and `newarray` will point to the same array as declared in (A). You need to remove that line. You also need to copy from the `mat` array.

```
public class MaxPop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rotation();
    }

    static void rotation() {
        int[][] mat = { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2 } };
        int[][] newarray = new int[mat.length][mat.length];
        int p;

        for (int i = 0; i < newarray.length; i++) {
            p = mat.length - 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < newarray.length; j++, p--) {
                newarray[i][j] = mat[p][i];
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < newarray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < newarray.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(newarray[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(mat[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

> 210
>
> 210
>
> 210
>
> 000
>
> 111
>
> 222

Comment: Actually i want to get a new version of the mat array each time the while loop will run,like this: the newarry will again rotate the new version of mat array to 90deg --->
while (k<2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < newarray.length; i++) {
            p =mat.length-1;
            for (int j = 0; j <newarray.length; j++,p--) {
                newarray[i][j] = mat[p][i];
                System.out.print(newarray[i][j]);
            } 
            System.out.println();   
        }
        mat=newarray;
k++;
    }